# How to debug executions of functions (in javascript)?

Tags: javascript

Many topics opened about this, but I have "different question", so opened a new topic. Need solution for **Firefox** (and **Chrome**):

How to see what function is executed, when I click something on `example.com`. for example:

```
XYZfunc(12,"carla bruno", "Monday");
$.post(data, "example.com")
```

shortly, to see everything what browser does at that moment.

P.s. in Firebug, I cant find that. Also, I dont need such traditional alerts, where I cant see what parameters were passed

[image]:

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events

Comment: In Firefox, hitting this key combination will show the Developer's palette, if your shortcuts aren't modified: `Ctrl + Shift + S`. Once the palette is up, you can use Debugger to track what you're after.

Comment: 1) **#adeneo**, i dont want just EVENTS. I want to get all details, of any particular executed JS command.   2) **blaze_125**, please, a bit more explanation, exactly HOW TO GET what I describe.

Comment: Once you have debugger up, find the function you want to track and put a breakpoint on it. When you trigger the function the breakpoint will stop execution and, you can then step through it. You can also go into the `console` tab and manually trigger the function directly from there by typing the function call in the textbox that is available to you on that tab. If you don't know what function is triggered by your click, then you'll want to right-click the element on the web page, and select "inspect element". Inspect the tag that comes up in the developers palette, reverse-engineer it.

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome, right click and hit 'Inspect'..

The sources tab would give you a view of your source files, you set break points there and see how your functions behave during execution

[image: The sources tab would give you a view of your source files, you set break points there and see how they behave during execution]

You use the icons on top when you decide to step through your code and go in and out of functions

[image: You use the icons on top when you decide to step through your code and go in and out of functions]

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, if your shortcuts aren't modified you can hit this key combination to get the developer's palette: `Ctrl + Shift + S`

Once the palette is up, you can use Debugger to track what you're after.

If you don't know what function is being triggered by your click, you can right click the element on the webpage, and select "inspect element" out of the context menu. That takes you to the "html tag" that you will then reverse-engineer to get the function being called. Though most often, the function call is pretty obvious and does not require much reverse-engineering... So once you know what function is being called....

Go back to Developer's palette, Debugger. Find the function you're after and put a break point on it. Once you trigger the function, code execution will stop at the break point and you can then step through the code.